# UTF8 lost in translation, HTML form from/to mysql

Tags: mysql, html, windows, linux, utf-8

An HTML form with utf-8 charset is stored TO a mysql db (in linux and windows)

then the form is filled FROM that DB, and surprise!

the `ó` simbol I've stored becomes an ugly `�`

Any idea of what can be happening?

I've configured my.ini default-character-set=UTF8, the same with php.ini with default_charset = "utf-8"

I've added  `<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />`
to the HTML

I've tried to use php iconv function, utf8_encode, configured collation to utf8...

I don't know what is happening with the utf8, thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

Does the `varchar` or `text` field used to store the value have a collation from the utf8 group (such as `utf8_unicode_ci`) If not, chances are your string is being stored in a single-byte character collation, giving you the bad result.